# How to open and close the Log window via code?

Tags: sas, dms

My Log window seems happend some font cahe issue, Sometimes it suddenly makes the font **BOLD** and that bothered me these days. Here is my first question: Dose anybody has any hints about the font issue?

Forunately I find the Log window return to normal if only I close and reopen it, so here comes my
second question: Is it possible to open and close the Log window in SAS DMS? If so, how to write it?

Comment: This question is not an actually programming puzzle, if it does not meet the rules of OS, please notify me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DM` statement to programmatically submit available [SAS Commands under Windows](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=hostwin&docsetTarget=n12pbrdi6hyw3gn1cjcrubshdxuk.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) or [SAS Display Manager Windows Window Commands](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=n01anipwof9byln1k37tuy8nwyfn.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) and most important for this question SAS Windows and Access Methods

The `LOG` command has a seemingly undocumented (online web docs) option `OFF`.  There is likewise a seemingly undocumented command `CLEAR`.  These commands are documented in Windows DM via F1 (Help) -- do a Quick Search for "SAS Windows and Access Methods".

```
DM 'CLEAR LOG; LOG OFF' LOG;
```

You might also want to check the DM windows font setting. Submit or issue `DLGFONT`

```
DM `DLGFONT`;
```

Finally, worst case, there is a possibility the SAS DM configuration file is damaged.   Locate `regstry.sas7bitm`, `profile.sas7bcat` in the `sasuser` operating system folder and , when SAS is closed, rename them so they are recreated anew at the next DM SAS session start.

If you are using a different SAS client, update your question and add your system setup.

Comment: Thank you,@Richard. I add "dm 'log off; log on' editor;" as a keyboard abbr now, it is very useful. By the way, I have tried regenerate `regstry` and `profile` files, it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Can you still consistently reproduce the problem ?  What font are you using ?  What code or activity occurs before the bold log ? Do you use any special OS locale settings ? Does it happen with other font settings (point size or different font) ?  Did you know you can alter some highlighting attributes of different log parts?  For instance, you can  issue command `LOG; color ERROR red REVERSE` to make logged errors pop *visually*.